# How many CPU render tiles/buckets should I set in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[Here](http://ark.intel.com/products/88195/Intel-Core-i7-6700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz) is a link to my CPU specs

```
# of Cores = 4
# of Threads = 8
```

How much CPU render buckets (or tiles) should I have while rendering? 8 or 12?

Comment: What do you mean "buckets" I am used to this meaning what Cycles calls *tiles*, but that doesn't seem to fit your context.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If we take blender specific wording, i mean "Tiles".

Comment: You can't change the number of tiles directly, Cycles uses however many tiles it needs to cover the whole rendered image.  You can change the size of the tiles under the *Performance* rollout though.

Comment: I know that, thank you. The thing i want to know, isnt i suppose to have 12 buckets while rendering in Cycles on this CPU? So i want some one who knows for sure to confirm this.

Comment: You mean how many are being rendered at a time?  Each thread can render 1 tile at a time, you can adjust the number of threads used under the Performance rollout as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have 8 CPU threads in total, you can render 8 tiles simultaneously at max. You can also lower this number to reserve remaining threads to other tasks your computer might be doing. The setting is here:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just another perspective...might be right or might be wrong. I've found that CPU Cores (processors) does not equal CPU Threads. On Windows 10, if you open up Task Manager and go to the Performance tab, you can see your computer has many, many threads running (mine showed 1800+). So I decided to try to increase the threads in Blender to beyond my CPU Cores (4). What I found was that Blender will render simultaneously the same number of tiles as you have threads. So for example, I set my tiles to 128 size and threads to 16, it will render 16 tiles at the same time even though I have only 4 CPU Cores. I have not found any optimum settings between tile size and number of threads. But play around and maybe you will find out there is a magic number

Comment: I would be VERY surprised if there is any benefit to using more threads than you have logical CPUs. Threads created by active processes is not the same thing as threads executing at once. No consumer CPU supports more than 2 threads per core, lower-end Intel chips (without hyperthreading) only support 1 thread per core.

Comment: When you set you tiles higher than you have logical cores, only the number of tiles equal to your logical cores will work, other tiles will be just waiting in queue. There is no point in setting more tiles than logical cores. Most CPUs have 1 or 2 logical cores per physical. Some CPUs have 8 logical cores per physical like IBM Power8 for example - such CPU can run 8 threads simultaneously.

Comment: So to sum it up, it might look like you are rendering 16 tiles at the same time, but actually only 4 are rendering at the same time. Same as with running 1800+ threads in Task Manager, only 4 threads can be active, others are just idle. A *scheduler* (which is part of OS) handles what threads to run (it juggles all those 1800+ threads) - usually based on thread priority setting.